# Using a function pointer on a non-struct/union

Tags: c

Is there a simpler way to 'bind' a function pointer to an object in C?

```
int add_two(int num) {
    return num + 2;
}
int main(void)
{
    struct thing {
        int num; 
        int (*add_func)(int);
    };
    struct thing xx = {.num=4, .add_func=add_two};
    int yy = xx.add_func(xx.num);
    printf("%d", xx.add_func(xx.num));
}
```

> 6

For example, is it possible to do something like this:

```
int x = 4;
&x->add_two();        // using pseudo-syntax
```

Or doing it in a single-go, such as:

```
(void*) "7" . add_two(7);
```

Or is the only way to use a function pointer within the context of a struct or union?

Comment: You're shoehorning something into C that it does not support. If you want to do OOP, choose another language.

Comment: What's this pseudo stuff even supposed to do? I don't get the question. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: C doesn't know the concept of objects, so no. You can't do this. You can use typedefs though, to make it more readable and easier to use.

Comment: Specifically, why can't you write `int x = 4 + 2;`? How are you _ever_ going to write clearer code than that?

Comment: C does know the concept of objects. But not *these* kind of objects.

Comment: @Lundin sure, obviously I wouldn't add a function to add 2 to a number. It's just a simple function so that it can basically be ignored other than its name/address for the function pointer.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Again, what problem is this supposed to solve?

Comment: @Lundin I was just curious as a beginner where function pointers are used, or if they're mainly for use within a struct.

Comment: Function pointers are mostly used for setting up callback functions, which is another ting entirely. In terms of generic programming, they can be used as function templates when you wish to perform different kind of operations on the same type of data. You _can_ use them inside structs to mimic C++ member functions and polymorphism, but the C syntax for that is rather clunky.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Function pointers have uses, but using them in a struct is not very common.

Comment: @klutt ok thanks, where are they more commonly used?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 One of the best applications is the compare functions for `qsort` in the standard library

Comment: @klutt this one? https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Yep. That function has a function pointer as one of the arguments, which is the compare function. That's basically the purpose of function pointers. Don't try to use them for OOP. C is not suitable for that.

Comment: @klutt -- oh I see, thanks for pointing that out (I wasn't able to locate it before you mentioned that). It's buried in stdlib.h: `typedef int (*__compar_d_fn_t) (const void *, const void *, void *);`

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Exactly, and you can see the same thing with `pthread_create` but there the function has the signature `void*(*)(void*)`

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. C++ was invented originally as a preprocessor for C compilers to do this kind of simple "object-oriented" programming paradigm.

Note that usually you'd want the reference to `xx` be passed to the method. For that you could use a macro such as

```
INVOKE(obj, name, ...) (obj)->name((obj), ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

Then you can use

```
int add_two(thing *this) {
    return this->num + 2;
}

...

    struct thing {
        int num; 
        int (*add_func)(thing *);
    };

    ...

    int yy = INVOKE(&xx, add_func);
    ...
}
```

And not need to write the `xx` twice; you could then make it a bit more complicated like put the methods into a separate virtual table object... but all in all that's about as far as you can get with standard C.

Comment: @antiiHaapala what is `xx`

Comment: And what problem does this `INVOKE` sort out?

Comment: you can save keystrokes in some cases

Comment: Btw it is wrong in C. It will not compile at any circumstances. It is not good to post not tested code as the answer.

Comment: Saving keystrokes is one of the worst rationales ever for using a particular language feature. People who don't like typing shouldn't be programmers, it's perhaps the single-worst choice of career if you don't like typing. Also for typing haters, there's the shift+ctrl+left arrow then ctrl+c and ctrl+v...

Comment: @Lundin or use compiler with auto-complete feature. It really saves unnecessary typing

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `you can save keystrokes in some cases` Yuo will save some keystrokes and you will have to write very long comment explaining why it is done this weird way :)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala still does not compile https://godbolt.org/z/qx3bGd

Comment: @0___________ here it works with making it a pointer: https://godbolt.org/z/oTfq7a.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Antti posted it as answer. Should work without changes. Generally I don't like answers not tested by the answering person. So it is not your job (or mine) to correct incorrect answers

Comment: added the missing `&`. Thanks for debugging it for me.

Comment: @Lundin if you have noticed, there are only two uses of macros - getting some definitions from headers in somewhat blackbox manner so that they expand in place to some C code, and saving keystrokes.

Comment: Avoiding code repetition is a valid reason. Saving keystrokes is not. Though C programmers are often way too concerned about avoiding code repetition, creating more problems than they solve in their attempts to avoid it.